# jquery ignoring upper&lowercase in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hello world i have an problem i am currently making experimental search boxes with divs for my homepage ..

now ive tried to ignore the upperand lowercase but nothing will going successfull so i will ask how i can get ignore the upper and lower case in my code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    function hide_divs(search) {
        if(search === "") {
            $("#sboxs > div").show();
        } else {
            $("#sboxs > div").hide(); // hide all divs
            $('#sboxs > div[id*="'+search+'"]').show(); // show the ones that match
        } 
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#search_field").keyup(function() {
            var search = $.trim(this.value);
            hide_divs(search);
        });
    });
});
```

html:

```
<div id="jOhAnNeS">heres the content of(Johannes)</div>
<div id="michael">heres the content of(Michael)</div>
<div id="TOM">heres the content(Tom)</div>
<div id="JERry">heres the content(Jerry)</div>
<div id="kIM">heres the content(Kim)</div>
<div id="joschUA">heres the content(Joschua)</div>
<div id="katY">heres the content(Katy)</div>

</div>
```

Comment: looks like you can't use pure CSS attribute selector, use `filter` or something like that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this function instead

```
function hide_divs(search) {

    var divs = $("#sboxs > div");
    var match = search.toLowerCase();

    divs.each( function(i,elem) {
        if ( elem.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(match) > -1 )
            $(elem).show();
        else
            $(elem).hide();
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you so much but i will ask i am making an multi search so like in the id is written `id="jacky Member Offline"` so then i am search for offline it shows every div with the idcontent offline. my old code going good but in your code i cant search for divs how has the content *offline*

Comment: to find a match anywhere in the ID just use indexOf(match) > 0 instead

Comment: thnaks for your help but now an other trouble comes on then i try to search for somebodey i cant search for michael no results its ignores the first word so then i look for ichael it find the buddy and then leave it blank nothing will be displayed ... hmmm ( > 0 )

Comment: sorry my mistake if ( elem.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(match) > -1)